# Getting like and comment counts album of page facebook using graph api

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to check the number likes and comments on my page album? i have make request with this code:

```
    $fields="id,name,description,link,cover_photo,count,likes.limit(0).summary(1),comments.limit(0).summary(1)";
    $fb_page_id = "my page id";
    $access_token="my access token";

    $json_link = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/{$fb_page_id}/albums?fields={$fields}&access_token={$access_token}";
    $json = file_get_contents($json_link);

    $obj = json_decode($json, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);



    for($x=0; $x<$album_count; $x++){

    $id = isset($obj['data'][$x]['id']) ? $obj['data'][$x]['id'] : "";
    $name = isset($obj['data'][$x]['name']) ? $obj['data'][$x]['name'] : "";
    $url_name=urlencode($name);

    $description = isset($obj['data'][$x]['description']) ? $obj['data'][$x]['description'] : "";
    $link = isset($obj['data'][$x]['link']) ? $obj['data'][$x]['link'] : "";

    $cover_photo = isset($obj['data'][$x]['cover_photo']['id']) ? $obj['data'][$x]['cover_photo']['id'] : "";
    $count = isset($obj['data'][$x]['count']) ? $obj['data'][$x]['count'] : "";

    $likes = count($obj['data'][$x]['likes']) ? $obj['data'][$x]['likes'] : "";
    $comments = count($obj['data'][$x]['comments']) ? $obj['data'][$x]['comments'] : "";
```

But i cant get the data how many likes and comment on my specific album page facebook. 
Please does anybody know how to get Facebook album like and comment counts? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What does $obj contain?

Comment: Forget my previous comments, albums seem to have likes. I tried to reproduce your call. Without ".limit(0)" it goes through just fine, with it, the response does not contain the likes.

Comment: Anyone can help me? Please..